# How do I translate a programmatically-created custom block?

Tags: 7, blocks, i18n-l10n

I am searching from long hours about this problem. I created a block programmatically, in my custom module, with `hook_block_info()`. I create its fields in `hook_block_configure()` and save values of fields with `hook_block_save()`. Then I get values of fields (variables) in `hook_block_view()` and then pass it to theme (template). I will not show you whole process because it is not necessary, I think. Something this way:

```php
function my_module_block_info() {  
  $blocks["mm_block"] = array(
    'info' => t("MM block"),
    'status' => TRUE,
    'region' => 'my_region',
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function my_module_block_configure($delta) {
  if ($delta == "mm_block") {
    $form['mm_block_desc'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Description'),
      '#required' => TRUE, 
      '#default_value' => variable_get('mm_block_desc')
    ); 
    // more fields
  }

  return $form;
}

function mm_module_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
  variable_set("mm_block_desc", $edit["mm_block_desc"]);
  // more variable_set
}
```

The problem is that the site is multilingual (has 3 languages), so I have to do everything three times. I created three blocks (mm_block_en, mm_block_es, mm_block_pl) for every language version and every of them has its own variables, etc. I need to make 10 diffrent blocks, so to have every language version, I have to do everything x3 (it gives me 30 blocks...). I don't think it is a good solution (so many blocks, so many variables (if one block has 15 variables, so multiplication it with 3 for 3 languages versions.. omg). And so a lot of code (3x configuration forms for every block, 3x saving every variable).

## How to translate custom block (created programmatically) in Drupal 7?

**- with not creating 3 separate blocks manually for every language version. I want to have one block in `Blocks` list in admin panel and there I want to be able to translate its fields (which were created programmaticaly in custom module).**

`Internationalization` module is installed. I tried with `Variable translation` module - but it is not giving me result I want.

Theoretically I can translate my block. I go to `http://mypage.local/admin/structure/block/manage/my_module/mm_block/translate` - but there is no fields to translate - there is only title and it is not translatable.

I think I tried everything. Can anyone help?

Comment: take a look it may give you an idea  https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/translations/2013-06-01/how-to-get-i18n-translated-block-programmatically#comment-9317805 https://gist.github.com/feldmayer

Comment: Thanks @berramou, but it is about displaying translated block. I can't translate my block and that is the problem.

Comment: How about https://www.drupal.org/node/304002?

Comment: But in that issue the block is created in block_schema() function, in .install file. I am creating my blocks with hook_block_info(). I'll try this way...